# Arithmetic on date series (not an index) in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

(Python 2.7, Pandas 0.9)

This seems like a simple thing to do, but I can't figure out how to calculate the difference between two date columns in a dataframe using Pandas. This dataframe already has an index, so making either column into a DateTimeIndex is not desirable.

To convert each date column from strings I used:

```
data.Date_Column = pd.to_datetime(data.Date_Column)
```

From there, to get elapsed time between 2 columns, I do:

```
data.Closed_Date - data.Created_Date
```

which returns an error:

```
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not a numpy.timedelta64
```

Checking dtypes on both columns yields datetime64[ns] and the individual dates in the array are type timestamp.

What am I missing?

EDIT:

Here's an example where I can create separate DateTimeIndex objects and accomplish what I want, but when I try to do it in the context of a dataframe, it fails.

```
Created_Date = pd.DatetimeIndex(data['Created_Date'], copy=True)
Closed_Date = pd.DatetimeIndex(data['Closed_Date'], copy=True)

Closed_Date.day - Created_Date.day
[Out] array([ -3, -16,   5, ...,   0,   0,   0])
```

Now the same but in a dataframe:

```
data.Created_Date = pd.DatetimeIndex(data['Created_Date'], copy=True)
data.Closed_Date = pd.DatetimeIndex(data.Closed_Date, copy=True)

data.Created_Date.day - data.Created_Date.day

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'day'
```

Here's some of the data if you want to play around with it:

```
data['Created Date'][0:10].to_dict()
{0: '1/1/2009 0:00',
 1: '1/1/2009 0:00',
 2: '1/1/2009 0:00',
 3: '1/1/2009 0:00',
 4: '1/1/2009 0:00',
 5: '1/1/2009 0:00',
 6: '1/1/2009 0:00',
 7: '1/1/2009 0:00',
 8: '1/1/2009 0:00',
 9: '1/1/2009 0:00'}

data['Closed Date'][0:10].to_dict()
{0: '1/7/2009 0:00',
 1: nan,
 2: '1/1/2009 0:00',
 3: '1/1/2009 0:00',
 4: '1/1/2009 0:00',
 5: '1/12/2009 0:00',
 6: '1/12/2009 0:00',
 7: '1/7/2009 0:00',
 8: '1/10/2009 0:00',
 9: '1/7/2009 0:00'}
```

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? (This seems to work fine for me, maybe you can include a few rows of your data and the output of `to_dict` e.g. `df[:2].to_dict`, so we can easily recreate this issue)

Comment: @hayden, I addressed your comment in an edit, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update: A useful workaround is to just smash this with the DatetimeIndex constructor (which is usually much faster than an apply), for example:

```
DatetimeIndex(df['Created_Date']).day
```

In 0.15 this will be vailable in the dt attribute (along with other datetime methods):

```
df['Created_Date'].dt.day
```

---

Your error was the syntax, which although one might hope it would work, it doesn't:

```
data.Created_Date.day - data.Created_Date.day
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'day'
```

With more complicated selections like this one you can use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html?highlight=apply#pandas.DataFrame.apply):

```
In [111]: df['sub'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Created_Date'].day - x['Closed_Date'].day, axis=1)

In [112]: df[['Created_Date','Closed_Date','sub']]
Out[112]: 
         Created_Date         Closed_Date  sub
0 2009-01-07 00:00:00 2009-01-01 00:00:00    6
1                 NaT 2009-01-01 00:00:00    9
2 2009-01-01 00:00:00 2009-01-01 00:00:00    0
3 2009-01-01 00:00:00 2009-01-01 00:00:00    0
4 2009-01-01 00:00:00 2009-01-01 00:00:00    0
5 2009-01-12 00:00:00 2009-01-01 00:00:00   11
6 2009-01-12 00:00:00 2009-01-01 00:00:00   11
7 2009-01-07 00:00:00 2009-01-01 00:00:00    6
8 2009-01-10 00:00:00 2009-01-01 00:00:00    9
9 2009-01-07 00:00:00 2009-01-01 00:00:00    6
```

**Be wary**, you'll probably ought to do something separately with these `NaT`s:

```
In [114]: df.ix[1][1].day # NaT.day
Out[114]: -1
```

.

*Note: there is similarly strange behaviour using `.days` on a timedelta with `NaT`:*

```
In [115]: df['sub2'] = df.apply(lambda x: (x['a'] - x['b']).days, axis=1)

In [116]: df['sub2'][1]
Out[116]: 92505
```

Comment: Although this method worked, I ended up taking a different route by creating Series outside of the DF, doing my manipulation to create a proper Days Series, and adding it back into the original DF.